# Does COPY COMMAND overwrite the output file?

Tags: postgresql

Does the COPY TO command overwrite the file?

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM Car) TO 'D:\study\s.csv' with WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

will the old data be deleted during the new copy?

I often need to copy data into one file

Comment: Have you tried this? There are SO questions that ask how to *append* to an existing file, so I'd guess that `COPY TO` overwrites

Comment: What happened when you tried?